# Join 2 tables using start date time SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables and, I want to create a join in SQL developer through the date times. Example, first table has a START_DATETIME 3/28/1999 15:38:00 and second table has START_DATETIME 3/28/1999 15:47:00, I want to join by date and hour only. Leaving out the min. How can I trunc the min to create a join between these tables. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `trunc()` function. The Oracle TRUNC function returns a date truncated to a specific unit of measure. In your case, you'll want to use HH, HH12 or HH24 for the hour format.

The syntax will be `trunc(a.start_datetime, 'HH24')`.

The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084) contain a much lengthier explanation about each of the
formats you can specify.

Comment: This is more accurate way of doing the join ! to_char would covert the date to text. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `to_char` function with appropriate format model, e.g.

```
from tab_1 a join tab_2 b on to_char(a.start_datetime, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24') =
                             to_char(b.start_datetime, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24')
```